# Vuejs how to compare dates with filter in list

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-filter

I'm learning vujs and got stuck on my own example with filter and date comparison. 
I got two similar strings (as dates '2020-02-02') in second row, and I should see the word 'today', but it doesn't work.

1. why on `typeof` in template my dates with filter are numbers?
2. what I'm doing wrong with comparison those dates? it's always `false`.

code you can see down here or https://jsfiddle.net/2awtdny4/9/

html:

```
<div id="app">

<div v-for="item in info">
  <div>
    <!-- I compare 2 dates as strings, and if it's true, I want to show word 'Today'  -->
    <span v-if="(item.date | yymmdd  === todayIs | yymmdd)" class="today">today</span>  
    <!-- else I want to show date as yyyy-mm-dd -->
    <span v-else>{{item.date | yymmdd}}</span>

    <!-- for some reason with filter date is NUMBER. why? in method and filter they should be stings -->
    <span>{{ typeof (item.date | yymmdd)}}</span>
    <span>{{ typeof (todayIs)}}</span>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

vue:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    info: [
      { date: "2020-02-01 10:00", text: "first text" },  // date format from backend
      { date: "2020-02-02 15:00", text: "second text" },
      { date: "2020-02-03 15:00", text: "third text" },
      { date: "2020-02-04 18:00", text: "fourth text" },
    ],
    todayIs: null
  },
  methods: {
     today() {
        var today = new Date(),
          todayDate = ('0'+today.getDate()).slice(-2),
          todayMonth = ('0'+ (today.getMonth() + 1) ).slice(-2),
          todayYear = today.getFullYear();

        var day = '';
        day = todayYear + '-' + todayMonth + '-' + todayDate;

        this.todayIs = day;
    }
  },
  filters: {
    // cut yyyy-mm-dd format and return date as string
    'yymmdd': function (date) { 
      var newDay = new Date(date),
          currentDate = ('0'+newDay.getDate()).slice(-2),
          currentMonth = ('0'+ (newDay.getMonth() + 1) ).slice(-2),
          currentYear = newDay.getFullYear();

      var day = '';
      day = currentYear + '-' + currentMonth + '-' + currentDate;

      return day;
    }
  },
  created: function () {
      this.today()
  },
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filters` only in mustache interpolations and v-bind expressions (the latter supported in 2.1.0+). Therefore it cannot be used like you have used it in the `v-if`.

You can create a function in your methods for comparing dates like the following :

```
compareWithToday(date){
    return this.$options.filters.yymmdd(date) === this.todayIs;
}
```

And then use this function to evaluate your `v-if` flag in template

```
<span v-if="(item.date | yymmdd  === todayIs | yymmdd)" class="today">today</span>
```

Above should be replaced with the following :

```
<span v-if="compareWithToday(item.date)" class="today">today</span>
```

Here is the working jsfiddle of above : https://jsfiddle.net/17mp6ofe/

Reference for filters : https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html

Comment: ohh, I thought v-if-statement is more flexible and it supports filters. thanks for the explanation ) so simple

Comment: @v-orlov Well the template syntax in vue is not that flexible. There are a lot of things that you can't do in it. 

Have a look at this : https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Using-JavaScript-Expressions

Answer (score 1):

You can not use filters like this. If you take a look at the browser console for your linked example, its is full of warnigns:

> vue.js:634 [Vue warn]: Property or method "yymmdd" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.

It is because [filters](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html) are usable in two places: mustache interpolations and v-bind expressions (the latter supported in 2.1.0+). Filters **should be appended to the end of the JavaScript expression**, denoted by the “pipe” symbol

Convert your filter to regular method and use computed property to convert your data one time instead of handling conversion in template (on every render)

```js
methods: {
  convertDate(d) {
    // conversion
  }
},
computed: {
  convertedData() {
      return this.info.map(i => ({ ...i, date: this.convertDate(i.date)}))
  }
}
```

[Sample](https://jsfiddle.net/o1n2zmwq/2/)

Comment: thank you! good approach to solving the problem with convert data on render. really useful for me